# Python - Constantly running an event handler without wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, python-2.x

I'm currently attempting to write a script using Python 2.7 (on Windows 7) that displays notifications using the notification software Snarl. Making the connection to Snarl requires the pySnarl module [(link)](https://github.com/EventGhost/EventGhost/blob/master/plugins/Snarl/pySnarl.py). The pySnarl module includes and Event Handler that basically checks to see if the notification has been closed or clicked on by a user and allows the script to run a function if such an event has occurred. I'm trying to implement this, however I cannot seem to get the Event handler to constantly listen for a click. There is an example script written by the author of the module [(link)](https://13044943641264701151.googlegroups.com/attach/6a8385e85fbe9c0f/pySnarlExtendedDemo.py?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrE6Rebtil-6xGgaKsLH2TinNBkUMg2axmNLiYheE-BySFLh3-K8w8YGrIG3WMjs6UfFKN76MN4OytQWcTmBcAKdVa5UidsiPMK1mfCPuEHbrWNNqxA) which shows use of the event handler and it works perfectly, but it gets the event handler to listen for clicks by making use of wxPython's app.MainLoop() command. I can't do this because my script is GUIless, I just want to use Windows Task Scheduler to run it every now and then in the background. I've tried a while True loop to get the Event Handler method constantly running but it does nothing except consume heaps of CPU. Here is my script (in the code formatting because I can't post more than 2 links right now):

```
    http://pastebin.com/4udVehg1
```

TLDR; I want an Event Handler to listen for events but I don't know how to get it running without using wxPython's app.MainLoop() feature and I want my script to be GUIless.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jono.

Comment: Check out [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I just needed to run the following at the end of my script:

```
while event_handling is True:
    win32gui.PumpMessages()     # Check for events, needs to be sent a WM_QUIT message to stop, handled in disable_event_handling()
    time.sleep(0.1)             # Check every 0.1 seconds
```

Then on a event being activated just call the following function to stop the script checking for events:

```
main_thread_id = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
event_handling = True

def disable_event_handling():   # Puts a stop to the loop that checks for events
    global event_handling
    event_handling = False
    win32api.PostThreadMessage(main_thread_id, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0)  # Sends a QUIT message to win32gui.PumpMessages(), without this it wouldn't stop checking for messages to pump
    return event_handling
```

Thanks for all the help and suggestions guys c:

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for PyPubSub : a package which provides a publish - subscribe Python API that facilitates event-based programming.

Check it out: http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/

**Edit**: PyPubSub is at https://github.com/schollii/pypubsub (since 2016)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it looks interesting but I have no clue how I'd go about getting it integrated. The binding I'm using uses win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents() and a handler class with the events defined within. How would I go about using PyPubSub to make that class constantly be on the lookout for events?

Comment: All you need to do is set up a subscription and then when you want to send an "event", you publish it. The website has examples. There's also another package called PyDispatcher, which is an alternative to pubsub: http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/